# Need some hints about SQL

Tags: sql, select, exists

I'm working on SQL right now and I've got these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Gym (
eid INT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(127) UNIQUE,
district VARCHAR(127),
area INT);

CREATE TABLE Trainer (
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(127),
birth_year INT,
year_credentials_expiry INT
);

CREATE TABLE Works (
eid INT,
id INT,
since INT,
FOREIGN KEY (eid) REFERENCES Gym (eid),
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Trainer (id),
PRIMARY KEY (eid,id));
```

I want to build a query that can tell me the names of the gyms with the district 'Casanova' where, at least, there is a trainer working.

I've been thinking about using the EXISTS operator but there must be a simpler method.
CAn anybody help me?

Comment: Since you're asking for hints and not answers, a hint would be to use an `inner join`.  Inner joining `table 1` to `table 2` will result in returning only records where `table 2` has records related to `table 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `INNER JOIN` between `Gym` and `Works` table will do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT g.* 
FROM 
    Gym g
    JOIN Works w
    ON g.eid = w.eid
WHERE
    g.district = 'Casanova'
```

If there isn't at least one trainer working in that Gym, this query would return nothing.

Comment: You can get multiplicates of the Gym records

Comment: Ah! thanks @RichardTheKiwi, added `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, the EXISTS query:

```
select *
  from Gym g
 where district = 'Casanova'
   and exists (select *
                 from Works w
                where w.eid = g.eid);
```

Why do you believe there should be a "simpler" method?
An alternative would be to list ALL columns from the Gym table in a three-way join, which will only work if there is a trainer to join against.

```
select distinct g.eid, g.name, g.district, g.area
  from Gym g
  join Works w on w.eid = g.eid
 where g.district = 'Casanova';
```

But given you need to use DISTINCT to get columns from the Gym table, I hardly feel it's "simpler".  You be the judge.